# Как корректно сделать корзину|SQL

Tags: sql

[image: Схема]

[image: табличка]

---

Доброго времени суток.
Как корректно сделать корзину?
Я думал присваивать товару id корзины и от этого отталкиваться, но sql не дает мне повторять id корзины- [image: ошибка]
Чет я завис

Comment: Формулируйте задачу, а не только свою попытку её решить. Мы не в курсе, что названо словом "корзина", и к какой заднице она тут прилеплена. Но то, что показано, наводит на мысль, что анализ предметной области вообще не проводился, а схема просто высосана из пальца. При таком подходе кривой результат более чем ожидаем.

Comment: А зачем у вас повторяется `idBasket` при записи в таблицу? Судя по тому, что вы пытаетесь записать, у одного клиента может быть несколько корзин, что ли? Вы определитесь с `use case` сначала. Есть сайты, на которых корзина у клиента строго одна, если он на сайте что-то в корзину добавил, то тут же это отражается и в приложении и везде. Тогда это один вариант и просто не повторяйте тогда `idBasket` при заполнении таблицы. А если у клиента может быть несколько разных корзин, то то, что у вас `Basket` видимо должно быть `BasketItem`, и схема должна быть другая.